# Hide NSView in StatusBar Application

Tags: xcode, nsview, statusbar

I have a small NSView (HUD-Style) in my StatusBar-Application.
If I get it right this NSView does not have a superview.

My problem is that I only want to show this view under certain programmatic circumstances.

What is the best way to show or hide this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to show this view in a borderless transparent window (NSBorderlessWindowMask).